# Can't load cals package

Tags: errors, compilation-error, cals

Here my problem is i can't load "cals package" on my document. I've tried to test this package in another separated document and it worked perfectly. I'm guessing that there are commands colliding with this package so i can't load the cals package. The error said :
`cals.sty error Command \thead already defined. \cals@thead@tokens}`

I commented the cals package so it can be compiled and assuming the problem will be resolved if when i uncomment (include) the cals package and it goes well without errors. I'm not providing the whole document, but here is all of my packages and preamble that i used so you can tell me which package or command made the cals package fail lo load and how to solve it. Please help me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[depth=2]{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{cals}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5   BAD BOXES   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hfuzz=60pt
\hbadness=10000

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newlist{ColEnum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ColEnum,1]{label = \arabic*), left = 0pt, nosep, 
    before= {\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
        after = {\end{minipage}}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}p{#1}}

\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{label=\textbullet, noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt, nosep, before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}, after=\end{minipage}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\setlength\bibhang{25pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cl}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lm}{Lemma}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definisi}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Contoh}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\rm\bf{Bukti}}

\renewcommand\tablename{Tabel}
\renewcommand\figurename{Gambar}



\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{10pt}

\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
\newcommand\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\setlength\parindent{1.25cm} 

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
\addtocontents{app}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}

\makeatletter
\def\ttl@mkchap@i#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipa#3\relax\beforetitleunit
    \vspace{\@tempskipa}%<<<<<< REMOVE THE * AFTER \vspace
    \global\@afterindenttrue
    \ifcase#5 \global\@afterindentfalse\fi
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipb#4\relax\aftertitleunit
    \ttl@topmode{\@tempskipb}{%
        \ttl@select{#6}{#1}{#2}{#7}}%
    \ttl@finmarks  
    \@ifundefined{ttlp@#6}{}{\ttlp@write{#6}}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\listappendixname}{DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
\newlistof{appendix}{app}{\listappendixname}
\setcounter{appdepth}{2}    
\renewcommand{\theappendix}{Lampiran\space\arabic{appendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftappendixpresnum}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforeappendixskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftappendixnumwidth}{.9in}
\newlistentry[appendix]{subappendix}{app}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubappendix}{\theappendix.\arabic{subappendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubappendixpresnum}{Appendix\space}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixnumwidth}{1in}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\listofappendix}{\begingroup
    \tocfile{\listappendixname}{app}
    \endgroup}

\newcommand{\myappendix}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{appendix}%
    \section*{\theappendix\space #1}%
    \addcontentsline{app}{appendix}{\protect\numberline{\theappendix}#1}%
    \par
}

\newcommand{\subappendix}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{subappendix}%
    \subsection*{\thesubappendix\space #1}%
    \addcontentsline{app}{subappendix}{\protect\numberline{\thesubappendix}#1}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \frontmatter %
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}   
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}
    
    \begin{spacing}{0.1}
        \tableofcontents
        
    \end{spacing}
    \begin{spacing}{1.5}
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
        \listofappendix
    \end{spacing}
    
    \mainmatter 
    \pagestyle{fancyplain}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

    
    \backmatter
    \bibliography{dafpus}
    \bibliographystyle{unejstyle}
    \nocite{*}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Packages `makecell` and `cals` are not comptible.

Comment: @Zarko I see. Thanks sir.